# How to save data from textbox to session when HREF link is clicked?

Tags: php, session

So here's my sample code.
I want the data in the text box will be saved to session when next page(a href) is clicked. Help me please. I'm kinda new to this language though.

```
   <?php
    session_start();
    ?>
   ....
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>

    <form action = "ecateg5.php" method = "POST">
    <table class="w3-hoverable">
        <tr class="thead">  
                <th>V.  ADDITIONAL .. . . . .</th>
        </tr>
    </table>        
    <BR>
    A.  Teaching skills
    <BR>
    <tr><td><TEXTAREA name="vcommenta" cols=40 rows=4></TEXTAREA></td></tr>
    .....
    D.  Personal qualities
    <BR>
    <tr><td><TEXTAREA name="vcommentd" cols=40 rows=4></TEXTAREA></td></tr>
    <BR> 
    <BR>
    <BR>
    <BR> 

    <div class="w3-center">
        <ul class="w3-pagination">
           ..........
          <li><a class="blue" href="ecateg5.php">5</a></li>
          <li><a href="ecateg6.php">6</a></li>
           .............
          <li><a href="ecateg6.php">»</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What's wrong with just submitting the form then processing the input and storing the relevant parts in the session (though that seems a little odd) with your `action` script (*ecateg5.php* currently).

Comment: I don't get your point. Sorry. But thank you for answering. Can you explain a little more, with some example? :( sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are going to **/ecateg5.php** page. You need to create a function that will take the posted value of a textbox in the **ecateg5.php**.

You also need to start session in the page that you want to go by using

```
session_start();
```

Here's a sample code for creating a **session** named **default**. And its value is the string in the textbox named **vcommenta**

```
$_SESSION["default"] = $_POST[vcommenta];
```